# Easy Type-Driven Random Mockup Construction in C++

Tags: c++, boost, stub, mockups, random

C++11's new Random or Boost.Random is really cool, powerful and flexible but cumbersome to use because of choice of *generator*, *distribution*, *seeding* of *state handling* (and in turn *re-entrency* and *thread-safety*), etc.

Often, however, when creating mockup objects in unit tests we really just want a *simple* way of creating a random object of a specific type and don't care that must about specific parameters. I personally think C++ STL and Boost lacks an easy and reusable way of accomplishing this. We would really just want to say, for instance,

```
std::vector<uint32_t> x(10);
some_nice_namespace::randomize(x);
```

using some global state and only if needed be more specific like

```
some_nice_namespace::randomize(x, rng_state);
```

or even more specific like

```
some_nice_namespace::randomize(x, rng(rng_state));
```

Anybody that have worked both in for example Matlab and C/C++ should be very aware of this gap in productivity. Does any C++ library implement any of these ideas? If not I will implement them myself and perhaps add them to Boost.

Comment: The opening premise doesn't make sense. How does a `<random>` gaussian distribution built from an engine even *compare* to `rand()`? They do completely different things. It's like saying that driving a car isn't as easy as eating cake, but eating cake won't get you to soccer practice...

Comment: As a side note, tests should not use random data, because then they are not guaranteed to be reproducable.

Comment: Ok, I removed the comparison with `rand()`. I still think my ideas are motivated.

Comment: @BjörnPollex: They are reproducible if the random number generator always starts with the same seed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Boost.Random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_random.html) doesn't seem to provide a class that binds a generator together with a distribution. You can make a template functor class that binds the two together.

[Boost.Foreach](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/foreach) and [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/range) are useful for writing generic code that operates on any container, array, or pair of iterators.

I've come up with the following which allows you to randomize a container concisely, once you've defined a functor that binds a generator and a distribution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/random.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/range/metafunctions.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/generate.hpp>

namespace rng // some nice namespace
{

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Binds a generator together with a distribution
template <class D, class G>
struct Functor
{
    typedef D Distribution;
    typedef G Generator;
    typedef typename D::result_type result_type;

    Distribution distribution;
    Generator generator;

    explicit Functor(const D& dist = D(), const G& gen = G())
    : distribution(dist), generator(gen) {}

    result_type operator()() {return distribution(generator);}
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Randomizes a collection (range) with the given functor
template <class Range, class Functor>
void randomize(Range& range, Functor& functor)
{
    BOOST_FOREACH(typename boost::range_reference<Range>::type x, range)
    {
        x = functor();
    }
}

} // namespace rng

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    namespace brnd = boost::random;
    typedef rng::Functor<brnd::uniform_int_distribution<>, brnd::mt19937> Dice;

    // This object could be made global if desired
    Dice dice(Dice::Distribution(1,6));

    std::vector<int> rolls(10);
    rng::randomize(rolls, dice); // Concise one-liner!

    /*  Could also use the following one-liner, but dice would be passed by
        copy and the resulting RNG state would not be retained. */
    // boost::generate(rolls, dice);

    std::cout << "Rolls:\n";
    BOOST_FOREACH(int roll, rolls)
        std::cout << roll << "\n";
}
```

By using template specialization, you can provide default generators for various numeric types:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename T>
struct DefaultFunctor
{
    typedef Functor<boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<T>,
                    boost::random::mt19937> Type;
    static T generate() {static Type fn; return fn();}
};

template <>
struct DefaultFunctor<float>
{
    typedef Functor<boost::random::uniform_01<float>,
                    boost::random::mt19937> Type;
    static float generate() {static Type fn; return fn();}
};

template <>
struct DefaultFunctor<double>
{
    typedef Functor<boost::random::uniform_01<double>,
                    boost::random::mt19937> Type;
    static double generate() {static Type fn; return fn();}
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class Range>
void randomize(Range& range)
{
    typedef typename boost::range_value<Range>::type value_type;

    BOOST_FOREACH(typename boost::range_reference<Range>::type x, range)
    {
        x = DefaultFunctor<value_type>::generate();
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    std::vector<float> noise(10);
    rng::randomize(noise);

    std::cout << "Noise:\n";
    BOOST_FOREACH(float sample, noise)
        std::cout << sample << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, I'll start using and improving it right away! Thanks.

Comment: It might be simplified with boost::bind, C++11's lambda expressions, and/or C++11's foreach.